# Default .NET sanitization on DropDownList (WebControls)

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, web-controls

I'm working with legacy code - WebControls with some .NET, got XSS problems.
In my code behind I've got simple DropDownList with ListItems added in a foreach like this:

```
 foreach (string enumValue in aEnumValues)
      pListBox.Items.Add(new ListItem(enumValue, enumValue));
```

But, when the dropDown is generated, value attributes of options aren't fully sanitized. The options in response body look like this:

```
<option selected="selected" value="&quot;>&lt;img src=2 onerror=alert(y65)>">&quot;&gt;&lt;img src=2 onerror=alert(y65)&gt;</option>
<option value="df">df</option>
<option value="&quot;dsdf>&lt;img src=2 onerror=alert(y65)> &quot;>&lt;img src=2 onerror=alert(y65)>    ">&quot;dsdf&gt;&lt;img src=2 onerror=alert(y65)&gt;    &quot;&gt;&lt;img src=2 onerror=alert(y65)&gt;  </option>
```

As you can see, for value attributes, not all characters are escaped. How can I fix this? Or is this some issue with WebControls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Values in ListControls are usually integers, if you can refactor it it would be more maintainable for any future changes. If you want a quick fix, u can need to encode the html parts:

```
foreach (string enumValue in aEnumValues)
    pListBox.Items.Add(new ListItem(enumValue, Server.HtmlEncode(enumValue)));
```

**Update(based on yr comment):**

if u look at the select tag it show html tags, have u ever seen a select tag showing html tags? I bet the select tag is hidden and it's for some logic in page. Usally the value attribute in the option tag is one word like integer or code:

```
<select id="card">
  <option value="visa">Visa</option>
  <option value="mc">Master card</option>  -- value is abbreviation of display text
  <option value="amex">American Express</option>
</select>
<select id="lstStates">
  <option value="CA">California</option>  -- value is state's code
  <option value="FL">Florida</option>
</select>
<select id="lstStaffs">
  <option value="1001">Daniel Smith</option>   --value is StaffId
  <option value="1008">John Doe</option>
</select>
```

[image]

Comment: Is this somehow mentioned in documentation? I mean I'd need some backup while talking about this with lead designer.

Comment: @Tenso It is important to be familiar with the controls that you use, I use a common set of controls and know (through personal testing) if they do encoding automatically.  As for official documentation, the [MSDN ListBox Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listbox(v=vs.85).aspx) page does contain a 'Caution' warning about this particular issue.

Comment: @Tenso There is also an old post (2008) [Which ASP.NET Controls Automatically Encodes?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sfaust/2008/09/02/which-asp-net-controls-automatically-encodes/) This does contain a list of WebControls and whether or not they automatically do any encoding.  This list is old and I would recommend testing out controls yourself in a sample project.

Comment: @daniel-b I know this looks abnormal, but It's not the case of refactoring. This application is quite complex and some of the controls are generated by propertiary frameworks with data taken from database. So it's not like I can put anything I want in those attributes. This issue appeared during automatic xss tests, so it's probably also problem with validation. But I believe, that good practice is to not rely only on one security measure, so validation will be improved, but I also think, that there should be some kind of encoding implemented on this particular control.